# Place backslash between words in string

Tags: python

I Want to convert com to newcom

```
com = R.E.M. - Losing My Religion.mp3

newcom = R.E.M.\ -\ Losing\ My\ Religion.mp3
```

I am doing this because Ubuntu terminal needs backslashes to specify spaces in paths.

This is just a string manipulation, what do I need to do?

Comment: Smells like the XY problem

Comment: The term "replace" may help you in your research.

Comment: We have tags ([tag:python]) no need to clobber your title with `[Python]`

Comment: okay thanks for downvoting , i will try replacing thanks kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newcom = com.replace(' ', '\\ ')
```

You need to replace a space with an (escaped) backslash and another space - that's exactly what Python's replace method is for.

Alternatively, an ubuntu terminal is fine with directories in quotes, e.g.

```
cd "hello world"
```

is just as valid as your solution, which would give

```
cd hello\ world
```

And perhaps cleaner to the user, and more accepting of other characters that might need to be escaped.

Answer (score -1):

Look into the replace() method in python:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm